# Limit of a Fourier Trasformation

Tags: analysis, solution-verification, lp-spaces, fourier-transform

Knowing that $f \in L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$, then $$\lim_{\epsilon\to0+}\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}e^{-i\langle x,\xi\rangle -\epsilon|x|}f (x)dx=\mathcal{F}_2f(\xi)$$ in $L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$, where $\mathcal{F}_2f$ denotes the Fourier transform in $L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$.

Meanwhile, at the first term after the limit we have a Fourier transform in $L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$, i.e. $\mathcal{F}_1(e^{-\epsilon|x|}f(x))(\xi) $ and therefore in theory to be well posed one should have $e^{-\epsilon|x|}f(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$, but I don't think it can be deduced in any way...
Furthermore, for the resolution I had thought of considering the sequence $\{e^{-\frac{|x|}{n}}f(x)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ which converges in $ L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ to $f(x )$ and furthermore using which is a Cauchy sequence and Parseval's theorem we obtain the convergence in $ L^2(\mathbb{R^n})$ of the sequence $\{\mathcal{F}_1(e^{-\frac{|x|}{n}}f(x))\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and therefore it must necessarily converge to $\mathcal{F}_2f$ (note that $\epsilon=1/n->0^+$ for $n->+\infty$ ).
I don't know if everything is right though, so if anyone can give me a hand, thank you very much.

Comment: "...but I don't think that can be resolved in any way...". Cauchy-Schwarz inequality shows how to show what you need.

Comment: But the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality is used with internal prouct... I don't understand How it can be used to demonstrate $e^{-\epsilon|x|}f(x)\in L^1(\mathbb{R^n})$

Comment: $$\int e^{-\varepsilon|x|} f(x) \le \left( \int e^{-2\varepsilon |x|} \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int |f|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

Comment: Ah you mean Holder inequality, ok thanks, the rest of demostration is ok? Or there is something wrong?